# Windows 7 UFD not responding after hard ejection

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

On a specific Windows 7 installation, I've got a USB flash drive that was removed while writing to it and since then on that specific machine the OS will not recognize it.

When I plug it in, it take a few minutes to appear but it's not functioning.. cant read/write or anything.

The UFD works fine the same machine on a different OS as well on other machines.

It seems that specific OS somehow remembers that UFD, how do I clear it's memory?

I've tried uninstalling the UFD under Disks in the device manager, after the restart and the reinstalling the UFD driver the issue remains.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried copying all the data off, formatting the drive then copying the data back?

Comment: Yes, no change.

Comment: Try [USB Oblivion](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/) and see if it helps (remember to select the "real clean" checkbox).

Comment: @Karan - USB OBlivion worked it out, Thanks. If you'll post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[USB Oblivion](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/) helped solve the issue in this case as per the comments above.

> USB Oblivion is a utility designed to erase all traces of USB-connected drives and CD-ROMs from the registry in Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 32/64-bit versions. The utility has a test mode of operation, i.e. without actually removing data from the registry, and, just in case, creates a .reg-file to undo any changes. There is also a fully automatic mode.

[image: 2]