# Remove automatically installed drivers in windows

Tags: windows-7

Is there any way to remove the drivers that are "automatically installed" (for instance when you plug in an USB device that has never been used with the computer before)?

Comment: You would need to go to the Device Manager and remove the driver/device.  I suppose you could write a script to do this if you had all the information required to do so.  Why would you do this the drive is required for the device to work, easier to just, prevent the driver from being installed through a group policy.

Comment: [USB Oblivion](http://superuser.com/a/580317/138343).