# External hard drive. USB Device Not Recognized

Tags: external-hard-drive

After unsafely extracting my external hard drive, I am now getting a USB Device Not Recognized error. How can I recover?

Comment: I believe that I understand what you’re saying, but I’m not sure.  Will you please try to rephrase your question to be more clear and provide more information (e.g., brand of disk, operating system on computer, …).

Comment: Is the drive recognised on another PC?

Comment: I removed hard drive without safe extracting. Now when I insert the disk I get this error. The disk recognized on another PC.

Comment: See if [this](http://superuser.com/a/580317/138343) helps.